# Changing the flex direction of a parent container makes the flex-grow of a child element stop working?

Tags: css, flexbox

Why does flex-grow stop working when I change the flex-direction of the parent container in my code?

In the following example, I have two divs, a parent flex-container div, and a lone flex-item child with a green background, and as you can see flex-grow works just fine

```css
.flex-parent{
    display:inline-flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}

.flex-child{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#99bb99;
    flex-basis:0px;
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-child">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    </div>
</div>
```

However, if I change the flex-direction of the parent container to column, flex-grow stops working and my container stops appearing, as you can see next

```css
.flex-parent{
    display:inline-flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.flex-child{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#99bb99;
    flex-basis:0px;
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-child">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I need to keep the overflow:hidden to be able to collapse the container by changing the flex-grow value to 0, so while removing the overflow property would make the container show, getting rid of it defeats the purpose, and everything does work fine when the flex-direction is set to row regardless, so I don't see why it's not working just for changing the value to column

Comment: its becasue of the flex-basis give it li 20 or 25 px

Comment: If that's the reason, why does it work when flex-direction is set to row when I also gave it a flex-basis:0px in that case? Either way, I am not really trying to make it expand to an arbitrarily pre-chosen height, I'm trying to make it to expand to a content-determined height (just like how in the flex-direction:row case it expands to a content-determined width)

Comment: in both cases it should not work so the real question is why it works in the first case. The second seems the logical result for me

Comment: Oh heck,
I supposed it worked in the first one because, it having flex-basis:0 and flex-grow:0 made the child be treated as having (in practice) no flex-dimensions (so to say it in a way), causing the contents to be treated as some sort of overflow, but that was just the way I wrapped my mind around it for it to make some sort of intuitive sense

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in having `overflow:hidden;`. This is because Flex wraps only when the initial main size of the flex items overflows the flex container. So to summerize.

**flex-direction: row** This is when the flex items are wider than the container.

**flex-direction: column** They must overflow the height of the container.

As a solution try setting a `height` or a `min-height` to the parent element. Hope this solves your problem.

```
.flex-parent{
    min-height: 20px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdvy60Lu/5/)**

Comment: But I'm not trying to overflow the flex container, in fact the container has no set dimensions so it can expand freely. 


Setting overflow:hidden on a flex child collapses the flex element if it also has flex-grow:0 and flex-basis:0px, and afterwards, I can de-collapse it by setting flex-grow:1 which maxes it expand to content size (making the parent container expand as well here).


Or well, it works that way when flex-direction is set to row, but not when it's set to column, I want to know why setting flex-grow to 1 won't cause the collapsed item to expand to content size in that case